# Jquery com codigo html dinamico

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, html5

Tenho uma função em Ajax que quando adicionada, insere/ atualiza uma pagina .php

```
 $("#recarrega-adt").click(function(event) {
   $.ajax({
                 url       : 'classes/consulta-aditivo.php',

            success : function(txt){
                 $('#view-full-adt').load('classes/consulta-aditivo.php');
            },
            error: function(result) {
                alert("Erro");
                /*sweet alert*/
            }
  });
 });
```

O problema que quando é realizada esta ação as outras funções JS/Jquery param de funcionar, pois este código foi inserido "depois" que  o restante foi executado.
Como devo resolver este problema? Encontrei o metodo `live()` e `on()`, porém ambos não surtiram efeitos... O unico modo que encontrei foi deixando o metodo na mesma pagina que é chamada mas não gostaria de fazer isso =/

Agradeço desde já.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".option-aditivo h3").on("click",function(){
    alert('teste');
    var id = this.id;
    var frase = this.title;
    $("<span class='frase-aditivo mover' id='adt"+id+"-enable'>"+frase+"</span>").appendTo("#papel");

    $(this).removeAttr('id')
    $(this).attr('id',id+"-plus");
    Draggable.create("[id*=adt]");
  });
 });
```

Comment: o código esta dentro do $(document).ready(function(){//seuajax}) ?

Comment: vc pode mostrar como estão sendo chamados as outras funções?

Comment: @LucaoA Estão Sim...

Comment: @Tafarel_Brayan Olá, Segue código da função a ser executada.

Comment: vc pode fazer da seguinte forma
ao invés disso: $(".option-aditivo h3").on("click", function(){}
faça isso: $(document).on("click", ".option-aditivo h3", function(){}...

Comment: @user48796 já verificou se no console não esta apresentando algum erro ? Porque dependendo do erro, é bem provável que "trave" seu javascript

Answer (score 0):

**Ao invés de usar assim:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".option-aditivo h3").on("click",function(){
        alert('teste');
        var id = this.id;
        var frase = this.title;
        $("<span class='frase-aditivo mover' id='adt"+id+"-enable'>"+frase+"</span>").appendTo("#papel");
        $(this).removeAttr('id')
        $(this).attr('id',id+"-plus");
        Draggable.create("[id*=adt]");
   });
});
```

**Tente asim:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click", ".option-aditivo h3", function(){
        alert('teste');
        var id = this.id;
        var frase = this.title;
        $("<span class='frase-aditivo mover' id='adt"+id+"-enable'>"+frase+"</span>").appendTo("#papel");
        $(this).removeAttr('id')
        $(this).attr('id',id+"-plus");
        Draggable.create("[id*=adt]");
   });
});
```